# How to see where does Windows 10's commit charge go?

Tags: windows-10, memory, memory-leaks

On my daily used laptop, the commit charge will rise to quite high eventually (27.8GB in the first attached image) while the accumulated commit size of all listed applications will be much smaller (the top 20 is about 7GB in total).

[image: Performance]

[image: Detailed Information]

Looks like there are some leaking memory commits. Is there any way or tool that can help me to see how the commit charge is composed of? (Looks like `vmmap.exe` and `procexp.exe` can only see process-wise information, `RAMMap.exe` can only see the physical memory)

Update 06/10:

1. For the second attached image, have used `Get-Process` under PowerShell to get the whole list, the accumulated commit size of all processes is about 10.5GB, still much smaller than the commit charge.
2. The commit charge will drop to a reasonable value (close to physical memory usage) after log out and re-log in.

Update 06/22:

1. The paged pool and the non-paged pool are 1.2GB and 1.4GB respectively, which should be not able to explain the difference between the commit charge (over 17GB) and the accumulated commit size (less than 9GB).

Comment: Dear close-voters: Just stop. This is _not_ a product recommendation question. OP is asking how to diagnose the high commit charge.

Comment: Not even sure how 3 poeple came to the conclusion that it is software recommendation related. Some close reasons are so random here...